# Regex based on presence of attribute and its value

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

I've a question about a regex, here my text:

```
1 200 file:test01.txt, action:read, User:dummy
2 201 file:test01.txt, action:write, User:dummy
3 202 file:unknown, keepalive , User:dummy
4 450 file:test01.txt, action:read, User:dummy
5 500 file:test01.txt, action:read, User:dummy
6 201 profiles, action:reload, User:dummy
```

I'd like to mach all rows where:

1. Second column is in 20[012]
2. action is not read
3. action is not present

So I would match:

```
2 201 file:test01.txt, action:write, User:dummy
3 202 file:unknown, keepalive , User:dummy
6 201 profiles, action:reload, User:dummy
```

I'm looking for a way to get row where: action is different from read and where action doesn't appear

I tried in many ways without success, here my last failure, the first line survives...

```
^\d+\s+(?<code>(20[012])).*(action:(?<!read))?
```

https://regex101.com/r/HGESxR/1

Any hints?

Thanks
Marcello

Comment: Because you said "action not read" to mean "action not 'read'", I initially thought you meant "action not present" to mean "action not 'present'", but I no see you mean "action:" not present. You need to edit to fix that.

Comment: Assuming it is your intent, I suggest you say, "action:", if present, is not followed by "read".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^\d+\s+(?<code>20[0-2])\s(?:.*action:(?!read)(?<action>\w+)|(?!.*action)).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n0QCc5/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<code>20[0-2])` - Group "code": `20` and then `0`, `1` or `2`
- `\s` - a whitespace
- `(?:.*action:(?!read)(?<action>\w+)|(?!.*action))` - a non-capturing group matching either

  - `.*action:(?!read)(?<action>\w+)` - 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible, `action:` substring, then Group "action" capturing any 1+ word chars, but not starting with `read` char sequence
  - `|` - or
  - `(?!.*action)` - immediately to the right, there should be no `action` after any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `.*` - 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible

Comment: A wee suggestion: change `(?!read)` to `(?!read\b)`. Congrats on your recent rolling of two zeros on your rep!

Answer (score -2):

As each line has a consistent pattern you could use the following regular expression.

```
^(?!.*action:read\b)\d\s+20[012]\s
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ltj5du/4/)

The regex engine (PCRE) performs the following operations.

```
^                     match beginning of line
(?!                   begin negative lookahead
  .*action:read\b     match 0+ chars except newline followed by
                      'action:read' followed by a word break
)                     end negative lookahead
\d\s+20               match a digit, 1+ spaces, '20'
[012]                 match '0', '1' or '2'
\s                    match a space
```

If you would like to match the entire line which meets the two requirements (rather than just determine if the requirements are met), tack `.*` onto the end of the regex. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ltj5du/6/)

As the negative lookahead, which is pinned to the start of the line, consumes no characters, the engine's internal pointer is at the beginning of the line when `\d` is matched.

Comment: I was perplexed by the downvotes as I thought I had answered the question, namely, how to match rows having certain properties. I see now, from both the OPs code and @Wiktor's answer, that the OP evidently also wants to capture two values in named capture groups. Had that requirement been stated I would have answered differently. Of course, the downvoters may have found my answer may be faulty for reasons other than the absence of the capture groups. If a reader spots a problem I would grateful for a comment.